# spring security, and basic auth only one entryPoint : how manage error on the other endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, basic-authentication

I need to add a basic auth in only one of my controller method
Other method don't have an auth, but still have a `@PreAuthorize` in order to check if the parameters are valid.

My issue is , httpbasic transform all the exception throwed by preAuthorize in 401 ( some should be 403, etc).
I have the feeling that all my endpoint are under a basic auth, not just the ones I have use `@Secured`

How can I avoid that?

My code:

```
@Controller
class MyController {

@Secured("BASIC_AUTHENTIFIED")
public void someMethodOnlyForAuthentified(){...}


@PreAuthorize("check(parameters)")
public void someMethodForEveryone(List<String> parameters){...}


}
```

And in my security config:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(login).password(password).roles("BASIC_AUTHENTIFIED");
}
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .and().csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: That is what you configured. What do you think `.anyRequest().authenticated()` does?

Comment: I still have the issue even if I remove it.

Comment: What I don't get why are you using `@PreAuthorize` to check if parameters are valid? Also what does `check` do? Anothering thing are you using Spirng Boot?

Comment: as pointed out `@PreAuthorize` means exactly what it means, it checks authorization. You dont do parameter validation in `@PreAuthorize`